# How to make a dropdown in HTML form from a range in Google Sheets - Appscript

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am studying appscript and I am stucked here, i dont know why I cant get the data from items!E2:E, it is a concatenate value of items!B2:B and items!C2:C.

This is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <label for="transaction-id">Transaction ID:</label>
      <input type="text" id="transaction-id" name="transaction-id"><br><br>
      <label for="item-details">Item Details:</label>
      <select id="item-details" name="item-details">
        <? var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("items").getRange("E2:E").getValues(); ?>
        <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
          <option value="<?= data[i][0] ?>"><?= data[i][0] ?></option>
        <? } ?>
      </select><br><br>
      <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
      <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity"><br><br>
      <button type="button" onclick="addItem()">Add</button>
    </form>
    <br>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Transaction ID</th>
        <th>Item Details</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
      </tr>
      <tbody id="item-list"></tbody>
    </table>
```

I want the dropdown to be the value on items!E2:E not "data[i][0]"
please help me :(

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQPfv.png)

Comment: Just curious here: why are you using `<? ` and `?>` in your code? - that looks like PHP to me. Does the options renders? - or just a single option `<?= data[i][0] ?>]`?

Answer (score 0):

Google Script:

```
function launchMyDialog101() {
  let html = '<select id="sel1" class="control" style="width:255px;height:35px;margin:10px 0 10px 0;"><option value="" selected></option></select>';
  html += '<script>window.onload = () => {google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((vA) => {let select = document.getElementById("sel1");select.options.length = 0;for (let i = 0; i < vA.length; i++) {select.options[i] = new Option(vA[i][0], vA[i][1]);}}).getSelectOptions();}</script>';
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html),"Load Select");
}

function getSelectOptions() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const rg = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 2);
  const vA = rg.getValues();
  return vA;
}
```

Sheet0:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Name1 | 1 |
| Name2 | 2 |
| Name3 | 3 |
| Name4 | 4 |
| Name5 | 5 |
| Name6 | 6 |
| Name7 | 7 |
| Name8 | 8 |

Dialog:

[image]